# angularjs directive refresh $compile:tpload exception

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive on my application that contains `tempateUrl` for view.

```
app.directive("testDir", function($window, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl : "app/tpl/test.html",
        link: function(){

        }
    };
});
```

when I refresh (F5) the page multiple times as quickly, the applcation throws an exception.

> Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template

If I don't use templateUrl and I use template, error does not thrown.

```
app.directive("testDir", function($window, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        template : "<div>mycontents</div>",
        link = function(){

        }
    };
});
```

But I have html templates on my application.

Answer (score 0):

Change `link = function(){}` to `link: function(){}`. Because you are returning an object that should contain `key:value` typed values. And make sure that you gave the right path to `templateUrl` if used.

```
app.directive("testDir", function($window, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            template : "<div>mycontents</div>",
            link: function(){

            }
        };
    });
```